# How to use the 'date' data type in SQL Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I'm currently trying to create an asp.net web app in c# using Visual Studio. I have a page that acts as a registration page for a parent or a child, depending on which radio button you select. When registering a child, you are required to enter DOB from three separate drop down lists. As it stands, I have the DOB data type in the database set as `varchar`, meaning the DOB for `05/05/2005` saves in the table as `'552005'`.

When I set the data type to `date` or `datetime` it throws this error:

> An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code Additional information: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Does this mean I have to parse the string into an int somewhere in the code? If so, how exactly and where in my code would it need to be? I'll include some screenshots along with my code.

Thanks in advance!

[Showing how my form looks and how DOB currently stores in table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ex2WQ.png)

```
protected void submitBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection connect = new SqlConnection("Data Source=THEBEAST;Initial Catalog=newregDB;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False");

    if (parentRadBtn.Checked)
    {
        if (firstNameBox.Text == "" || surnameBox.Text == "" || postcodeBox.Text == "" || teleBox.Text == "" || emailBox.Text == "" || userBox.Text == "" || passwordBox.Text == "")
        {
            Response.Write("<script>alert('Please ensure all fields have an entry');</script>");
            successLabel.Text = ("");
            userBox.Text = "";
            firstNameBox.Text = "";
            surnameBox.Text = "";
            postcodeBox.Text = "";
            teleBox.Text = "";
            emailBox.Text = "";
            passwordBox.Text = "";
        }
        else
        {
            SqlCommand pa = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO parent(parentID, firstname, surname, postcode, telephone, email, password) VALUES (@parentID, @firstname, @surname, @postcode, @telephone, @email, @password)", connect);
            pa.Parameters.AddWithValue("@parentID", userBox.Text);
            pa.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstname", firstNameBox.Text);
            pa.Parameters.AddWithValue("@surname", surnameBox.Text);
            pa.Parameters.AddWithValue("@postcode", postcodeBox.Text);
            pa.Parameters.AddWithValue("@telephone", teleBox.Text);
            pa.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", emailBox.Text);
            pa.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", passwordBox.Text);

            connect.Open();
            pa.ExecuteNonQuery();
            connect.Close();
        }

        if (IsPostBack)
        {
            userBox.Text = "";
            firstNameBox.Text = "";
            surnameBox.Text = "";
            postcodeBox.Text = "";
            teleBox.Text = "";
            emailBox.Text = "";
            passwordBox.Text = "";
        }
    }           
    else if (childRadBtn.Checked)
    {
        if (firstNameBox.Text == "" || dayDobList.Text == "" || monthDobList.Text == "" || yearDobList.Text == "" || genderList.Text == "" || userBox.Text == "" || passwordBox.Text == "")
        {
             Response.Write("<script>alert('Please ensure all fields have an entry');</script>");
             successLabel.Text = ("");
             userBox.Text = "";
             firstNameBox.Text = "";
             dayDobList.Text = "";
             monthDobList.Text = "";
             yearDobList.Text = "";
             genderList.Text = "";
             passwordBox.Text = "";
         }
         else
         {
             SqlCommand ca = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO children(childID, firstname, dob, gender, password) VALUES (@childID, @firstname, @dob, @gender, @password)", connect);
             ca.Parameters.AddWithValue("@childID", userBox.Text);
             ca.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstname", firstNameBox.Text);
             ca.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dob", dayDobList.Text +  monthDobList.Text +  yearDobList.Text);
             ca.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gender", genderList.Text);
             ca.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", passwordBox.Text);

             connect.Open();
             ca.ExecuteNonQuery();
             connect.Close();
         }

         if (IsPostBack)
         {
             userBox.Text = "";
             firstNameBox.Text = "";
             dayDobList.Text = "";
             monthDobList.Text = "";
             yearDobList.Text = "";
             genderList.Text = "";
             passwordBox.Text = "";
         }              
     }
 }
```

Comment: how do you tell 1-12-2016 from 11-2-2016?

Comment: Why do you have to put the date as nvarchar?  Why not "date"?  the value you'll enter will be in the format "2014-01-01".

Comment: Auguste, as I said in the original question, when I change it to type 'date' or 'datetime' I get an error message. I thought that by changing the type to date it would automatically take the input '552015' and make it 5/5/2015 or something along them lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you have some data in your table with old format `'552005'`, so when you want to change the column type you get error. So you have two options:

1- Delete anything from that table, change the column type and start saving dates as `datetime` or `datetime2`.

2- Convert all of the current data to a date string eg. `'05/05/2005 00:00:00'` and then change the column type to `datetime`.

UPDATE:

Also don't forget to add data type to your SqlParameters:

```
SqlParameter dob = new SqlParameter("@sinceDateTime", SqlDbType.DateTime);
dob.Value = new DateTime( Int32.Parse(yearDobList.Text), Int32.Parse(monthDobList.Text), Int32.Parse(dayDobList.Text));
ca.Parameters.Add(dob);
```

Comment: Every time I test the table, I delete the entries straight away. I have a clear table, changed type to date or datetime and am getting the error when trying to submit values to the table. :(

Comment: You're missing the datatype as well, see the update @ACostea

Comment: There is no DateTime constructor that takes 3 strings.  Maybe you mean this one?  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xcfzdy4x%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Ok, so I added the code in, but in the first line at 'SqlDbType.DateTime);' it is saying 'The name SqlDbType does not exist in the current context'.

Also, on the second line, there are errors with '(yearDobList.Text, monthDobList.Text, dayDobList.Text);' saying 'Argument 1: cannot convert from string to int'.

Where am I going wrong? Thanks for the help by the way!

Comment: For the first one you have to add a System.Data dll reference to your project. see the update for the second one@ACostea

Answer (score 0):

need a date, make a date:

```
new DateTime(int.Parse(dayDobList.Text), 
             int.Parse(monthDobList.Text), 
             int.Parse(yearDobList.Text))
```

Comment: @Siyual -- exactly... the code above will solve this problem he has by replace the line that says `ca.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dob", dayDobList.Text +  monthDobList.Text +  yearDobList.Text);` which is clearly wrong and will fail.  since it is creating a string instead of a date. As I'm sure you knew ;()

Comment: So where would I put the new DateTime section of code? I thought it should go in the beginning where I create the SqlConnection but it was throwing up errors. I appreciate the help I just don't really know what to do with it..

Comment: I guess it is not very helpful then.  @Yaser gave an example about how to use this as a parameter to your sql calls.